# How to migrate and existing logic app from consumption model to the new standard model?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

There is a new single tenant standard model for Azure Logic Apps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare). Is there an easier way to migrate existing logic apps build on the consumption model to the new standard model other than recreating the app from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

One of the workarounds that you try is to use the code view of your consumption workflow and paste it into your standard logic app workflow. To do so, first, create your workflow in your standard logic app, then proceed to the previous step. Also, we need to make sure that `"kind":  "Stateful"` or `"kind":  "Stateless"` is being added after the definition.

**EXAMPLE:**
Here is the workflow that I'm using in my logic app - consumption plan.

[image]

And this is the workflow that I was able to pull after I pasted the code view of the consumption plan to standard.

[image]

Comment: But when you say "construct your workflow in your standard logic app," how is this not adding each action from scratch. Maybe there is no migration path for this yet. Which is ok when you have relative small apps, but an app with many many actions will be insane.

Comment: Construct your workflow in the sense Navigate to your standard logic app -> Workflow -> Add(Create a workflow) -> Open your workflow -> Code (in leftpane) -> Then paste your Consumption Logic app workflow code here

Comment: By doing this there is no need to manually adding each and every action to your workflow the whole workflow from your consumption plan will be copied to your standard logic app

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be no documented approved way to convert a consumption LA to standard in any traditional way. maybe for some simple logic apps, but anything complicated would not work. i believe this is because some connectors are different in standard LA vs consumption. the SQL connector for example has a built-in version as well as an Azure version.

I just tested this in my environment by copying the "schema" portion of code from the "export template" blade of a moderately complicated test consumption app and tried to paste this into the code for a standard stateless LA (keeping the "kind": "Stateless" parameter) and i ran into errors of some connectors not being found when i tried to save.

[image]

**To fix this i would have to address each connector individually, so i may as well had just created the standard LA from scratch**

consumption:

[image: consumption design]

standard:

[image: standard LA design]

Comment: Its also really really slow to edit/add all those connectors. Classic Microshaft, they make a newer "better" version of their product which is slower and more difficult to use. But probably accomplishes some of their backend functions better so makes them happy (but not the customer).

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Export tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/export-from-consumption-to-standard-logic-app) in preview as of October 2022. Disclaimer: I haven't tried it, and preview features can be subject to dramatic changes.