# Migrate Consumption Logic App to Standard

Tags: migration, azure-logic-apps

This is a follow-on to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69915297/how-to-migrate-and-existing-logic-app-from-consumption-model-to-the-new-standard)

That answer covers a basic case, but does not work if the workflow includes DB access, at least that is what I found, for SQL Server. Further, the only SQL Server operation offered in Standard is Execute Query, which is a significant dis-improvement from Consumption

So far, I have not been able to find any way to achieve this migration without manually re-coding the workflow - both time-consuming and risky, necessitating extensive regression testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the other thread it does work but there are few changes that are required.

> Further, the only SQL Server operation offered in Standard is Execute Query, which is a significant dis-improvement from Consumption.

Sql Server isn't available in built-in connectors but are available in Azure connectors. Here is the screenshot for your reference:

[image]

> That answer covers a basic case, but does not work if the workflow includes DB access, at least that is what I found, for SQL Server.

One workaround is you need to make few changes in the code view of Sql Connector in order to make the connector work. Consider the below code view.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Get_rows_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql_1']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[STATION]'))}/items"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Get_tables_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql_1']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_rows_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "sql_1": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Your suscription>/resourceGroups/<Your resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql-4",
                    "connectionName": "sql-4",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<Your suscription>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the changes you need to set in your logic.

- Remove parameters{ } i.e..

  ```
  "parameters": {
          "$connections": {
              "defaultValue": {},
              "type": "Object"
          }
      },
  ```

  ```
  "parameters": {
      "$connections": {
          "value": {
              "sql_1": {
                  "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Your suscription>/resourceGroups/<Your resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql-4",
                  "connectionName": "sql-4",
                  "id": "/subscriptions/<Your suscription>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/sql"
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Replace `"connection": {"name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql_1']['connectionId']"}` in your Get_rows_(V2) and Get_tables_(V2) with `"connection": {"referenceName": "sql"}`
- Add the kind of your workflow in the end i.e.. `"kind": "Stateful"`

After changes Below is the code view of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Get_rows_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "sql"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[STATION]'))}/items"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Get_tables_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "sql"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_rows_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the SQL option ... I did see the code differences; I was hoping that maybe there was a conversion / migration tool as we have a LOT of SQL references. It looks as though that would be possible?

Comment: @JohnD There are currently no such migrating tools available.