# Best way to define a SQL Server connection in the Standard Logic App

Tags: sql-server, connection, azure-logic-apps

I'm currently converting a number of Consumption Logic Apps to Standard; I see the Connections are now external to the Logic App, in itself, an improvement. But since you can't add a Connection (only remove one), the only way to add a Connection is to create a dummy App and make the Connection on-the-fly. This makes it pretty awkward deploying a new Standard Logic App i.e. from one Tenant to another, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment we can only add the connections manually as said in [Migrate Consumption Logic App to Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939602/migrate-consumption-logic-app-to-standard) since there few differences between the consumption and standard logic apps.